# How to close bootstrap popup on submit in VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to hide a bootstrap popup when the "Add Location" button is pressed and when the field is filled.

```
<template>
  <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">{{popupTitle}}</h5>
        <button type="button" @click="closeModal" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><input type="text" v-model="addBinLocation"></p>
        <span v-show="errorTxt" class="error">Field cannot be empty</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button @click="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Location</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:['popupTitle'],
    data(){
      return{
        addBinLocation: '',
        errorTxt: false,
      }
    },
    methods:{
      btnAdd(){
        if(this.addBinLocation === ''){
          this.errorTxt = true;
        }
        else{
          this.$emit('addLocation', this.addBinLocation);
          this.addBinLocation = ''
          this.errorTxt = false;
        }
    },
    closeModal(){
      this.addBinLocation = ''
      this.errorTxt = false;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  .error{
    color:red
  }
</style>
```

in the btnAdd function else section, when the user has filled the field, I want the modal to close when the button is clicked. I tried refs, by giving the modal a ref and adding this code but it is not working

```
this.$refs.myModal.hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `v-if="showModal"` in your first modal div. And set this.showModal to true when the modal should be visible and set it to false when you want to hide the modal `this.showModal = false`

Answer (score 0):

I have able to hide the popup by adding this in the addBtn function

```
 $('#staticBackdrop').modal('hide');
```